# How to adjust/normalize/standardize mean?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation

I am making a reviews/ratings section for a website, with ratings that range from 0-5 stars. I am not confident that the users of this system will all have the same idea of what these stars mean, so I'd like to pin the average to 3 and pin the standard deviation to 1, and then display the adjusted values for the ratings that the users enter. So if users rate most things 4, then 3 becomes the new 4. Or if users rate most things 0, then 3 becomes the new 0, and all other values are adjusted accordingly (not in the way they are stored, just in the way they are displayed). How should I go about doing this? What is the terminology I should be searching for? I would call this normalizing the data, but the internet seems to have a lot of different ideas about what "normalizing" means.

Comment: So for instance, if the average real rating is 0, then 3 is 0, so if someone rates something as a 2, that will translate to being displayed as a 5.

Comment: The arithmetic of it is usually called "standardization."  But there are fundamental issues lurking here.  After all, if you are constantly changing the meaning of the numbers being presented to users, why can you have any faith that the rating assigned by an earlier user is at all comparable to a rating assigned by a later user?  How can you even check that, given that the scale is constantly changing?

Comment: I'll present both the real and adjusted ratings to the user, so they will be able to see both.

Comment: Because the standard method of using a table or bar charts to display the full distribution of responses (there are, after all, only six choices) provides so much more information in a more useful form than standardized scores, consider focusing on communicating the distribution and the intended meanings of the stars as clearly as possible rather than performing calculations that might only confuse the users.

Comment: If you make the mean 3 and the sd 1, then you will have ratings that fall outside the 1 to 5 scale and you will have fractional ratings.  Also, if the distribution of a person's ratings is bimodal (as I suspect it may be for some people) then taking the mean at all may be problematic.

Comment: I'll just put a floor and a ceiling on the new ratings to solve the first problem, and I'll round them to solve the 2nd.  In the case of bimodal ratings, I agree that should discourage people from using the mean as the sole determinant of how much they will like the thing, but I still think it's worth showing, and showing the mean is a business requirement anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can just scale the mean linearly:

```
mu2 = standardized average
mu1 = average
muall = population average
sigma1 = standard_deviation
sigmaall = population standard deviation

mu2 = (m1 - muall) * (sigma1/sigmaall) + 3
```